# SLD - styling geometry collections in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld, geometrycollection

I’m trying to style a geometry collection column (PostGIS)  that stores both polygons and points in each record.

I already read the geoserver manual on how to style mixed geometry types and I don’t think this is possible when you have mixed geometry types in the same record.

I’m using geoserver 2.12.0.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I can't comment but your answer maybe here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35292/mixed-geometry-types-styling-with-geoserver-2-2

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the structure of your collections it might be possible to pull out the individual geometries using the [`getGeometryN` function](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#geometric-functions) which returns the Nth geometry of a collection.

In general, I would avoid storing mixed geometry collections in favour of multiple geometry columns. Maybe a materialised view would help?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot code in Java I'm afraid there are no solutions, unless the multi-geometry structure is regular, for example, if there are always 3 sub-geometries, then you can use getGeometryN and test its type in 3 different rules, summing up to 9 separate rules (one with a filter testing point for geometry 1, one for testing line for geometry 1, and so on).

If you can code in Java, then you could easily write a filter function that returns a multi-X geometry of the chosen type, e.g., given a geometry collection return a multipoint (the subset of points in the original collection), or a multiline, or a multipolygon. Then you can have only 3 rules working against geometry collections of whatever size, and styling the specific geometry subset accordingly.

See this tutorial on how to write functions: https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
In the end, I adopted one of the solutions provided in the geoserver guide "Styling mixed geometry types".
I've created extra geometry columns, each for each type.